# Greater than in python?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have 3 props: prop1, prop2, and prop3. I want a python scrip to work where it will determine if prop1 is is greater than or equal to prop 2. Also, I want it to determine if it is less than. If it is greater than or equal to, prop 3 will be true (boolean). Else, it will be false. Here is my code:

```
def property(cont):    
own = cont.owner

if 'Ammo_Reserve' in own and 'Ammo_Fired' in own:

    reserve = own['Ammo_Reserve']
    fired = own['Ammo_Fired']
    sit1 = own['Situation1']   

else:
    print('No properties found in object')
    return

if reserve < fired:
    print('Ammo_Reserve is less than Ammo_Fired')
    sit1 = True

else:
    print('Ammo_Reserve error (less than)')

if reserve >= fired:
    print('Ammo_Reserve is greater than or equal to Ammo_Fired')
    sit1 = False

else:
    print('Ammo_Reserve error (greater than or equal to)')
```

Why does this not work?

Also:

Ignore the extra logic.
[image]
[image]

Comment: prop3=prop1>prop2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Python and not specific to Blender.

Comment: @X-27 I agree, that is more likely

Comment: I think the main problem is that it is not setting the sit1 property correctly.

Comment: yes you should do `own['Situation1']  = True` not `sit1 = True` , if you assign new value to `sit ` it will be separate than `own['Situation1'] `

Comment: @Chebhou It still doesn't work. When reserve is clearly less than fired, it is still false.

Comment: the other thing is the test i think it's incorrect `if 'Ammo_Reserve' in own`

Comment: Yes, I clearly have Ammo_Reserve and Ammo_Fired in the object with the script.

Comment: I'll test it and be back

Comment: Ok it is working if you did replace   `own['Situation1'] ` instead of `sit1 `

Comment: It is not for me. I do not understand why. I have the 2 properties I need, along with sit1

Comment: i'll write an answer  with example file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23442/discussion-between-chebhou-and-blackhole).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this ***Extremely*** easily.

at least from the way your question is worded, I think this is what you want.

Enable *debug properties* to see ***Prop 3*** display in the BGE, and then change either ***Prop 1*** or ***prop 2*** to make one higher that the other, and ***Prop 3*** will now change to be **true** or **false**.

[image: Lame Logic Setup]

Comment: If it is that simple, then please answer the following: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29152/properties-not-working?noredirect=1#comment45695_29152. I was told to use python.

Comment: I tried to decipher your logic in that file, and it is Quite confusing. One possibility is that it will not work if you have it detecting if (any property)  is greater or lower than ***Prop Name*** . Use ***Prop_Name*** instead.

Comment: I did. I have them as prop_name format.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `sit1 = own['Situation1']` then `sit1` will have the value of `own['Situation1']` but it's not the same variable ( because of the way python works ), so you should assign the new value to `own['Situation1']` itself, this should work ( i have removed the second if/else since it is the exact opposite of the first ) :

```
import bge
from bge import logic

def property(cont):    
    own = cont.owner

    if 'Ammo_Reserve' in own and 'Ammo_Fired' in own:

        reserve = own['Ammo_Reserve']
        fired = own['Ammo_Fired']
        sit1 = own['Situation1']   

    else:
        print('No properties found in object')
        return

    if reserve < fired:
        print('Ammo_Reserve is less than Ammo_Fired')
        print('Ammo_Reserve error (greater than or equal to)')
        own['Situation1'] = True

    else:
        print('Ammo_Reserve error (less than)')
        print('Ammo_Reserve is greater than or equal to Ammo_Fired')
        own['Situation1'] = False

cont = logic.getCurrentController()      
property(cont)
```

example file [image]

Comment: This is driving me nuts; I have the exact same outcome except sit1 not changing. I **clearly** have reserve as 1 and fired as 10, and sit1 stays false!

Comment: @blackhole did you try my file ?

Comment: Yes I did. I've had problems like this a **lot.** Problems where I replicate something to the exact, it doesn't work, I show someone, no one fixes it, and my question gets abandoned.

Comment: I've added pictures. I have your script and that!